# How to import css for Angular Material Datepicker?

Tags: angular, angular-material, materialdatepicker

I'm using Bootstrap for my angular project.

In my angular.json, I added bootstrap like this:

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
    ],
```

I need to add a datepicker to my project.

Angular Material provides a [datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview). In order to use it, I had to install Angular Material:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

Among other things it adds CSS styles to the project.

When I select Indigo-Pink as a theme, it adds this to the styles:

```
    "styles": [
      "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
      "src/styles.css",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    ],
```

**Problem**: This overwrites my Bootstrap styles and breaks some things. For example, my links styled with the class "nav-link" can't be clicked anymore.

However, the datepicker works fine:

[image]

**Question:** Is there a way to import the CSS for Angular Material Datepicker without overwriting Bootstrap?

**What I tried so far**

I took a look at node_modules and I found a datepicker-theme.scss
in

```
./node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/_datepicker-theme.scss
```

and I tried to include only that file in my styles, like this:

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
      "./node_modules/@angular/material/datepicker/_datepicker-theme.scss",
    ],
```

While the datepicker works, it looks weird:

[image]

[image]

I probably have to import more files but which files could it be?

Angular CLI: 14.2.5

Node: 16.10.0

Angular: 14.2.5

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I am having a similar issue trying to use only the datepicker from angular/material in an existing project that doesn't use angular/material at all.

Comment: If you're using bootstrap as "inspiration .css" I suggest you use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) It's a library of components well proben and robust

Comment: @c0r3yz No, sorry, I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

You can define what you pull in by creating a styles.scss file and only including the date-picker theme:

In your styles.scss file add something like:

```scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$my-primary: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette, 500);
$my-accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette, A200, A100, A400);
$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $my-primary,
    accent: $my-accent,
  ),
  typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
  density: 0,
));

@include mat.core();
@include mat.datepicker-theme($my-theme);
```

You will then need to include this file in the styles array in your angular.json.

Answer (score 0):

Please insert below code into your styles.css which is located in your src folder.

@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";

You can select any css under the prebuilt-themes folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).